# Lucene query in Liferay

Tags: lucene, liferay

I am looking for how to create a lucene query for the condition – className  AND (“Apple-Orange” OR “Apple Banana” OR “Apple Shake”)
I tried

```
BooleanQuery specialityQuery = BooleanQueryFactoryUtil.create(searchContext);
specialityQuery.setQueryConfig(searchContext.getQueryConfig());
specialityQuery.add(contextQuery, BooleanClauseOccur.MUST);

BooleanQuery idFilter = BooleanQueryFactoryUtil.create(searchContext);

for (String speciality : specialities) {
     TermQuery termQuery = TermQueryFactoryUtil.create(searchContext, "fruit", speciality);
     idFilter.add(termQuery, BooleanClauseOccur.SHOULD);
     LOGGER.info(" Term Query " + idFilter);

}
specialityQuery.add(idFilter, BooleanClauseOccur.MUST);
```

But this doesn’t work. Any other ideas?

P.S - Question posted on Liferay as well - https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/48383912

Tina

Comment: what does it mean it's not work?